# How to retain the change in the value of multiple buttons(done using AJAX) after the page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

In my webpage, I have multiple buttons. On clicking, they are supposed to call a javascript function and their value should toggle between 'A' and 'B'.
Here is what I have done:

```
<input type="button"  id = "<?print $id1?>" value="A" onclick= 
"updateLike('<?print $row2['comm_id']?>','c'); "/>
```

The above section of code is in a for loop where the value of id keeps changing.

Since am using AJAX(without jQuery), as soon as I reload the page, the value of these button change back to A,irrespective of whether they were clicked or not.

How can I get around this without storing the value of each and every button in the database?

The number of buttons vary and could be huge.

**Edit:** I think I wasn't clear before. I am using a login form. On successful login, it should display a page for that particular user. This page is the one am talking about above. Will storing cookies will still be relevant in this case?

Comment: Your question is too broad, but look into session variables.

Comment: yeah. But I have read that too many session variables is not a good idea.

Comment: The behavior you are requesting doesn't even appear to need php, so I am not sure what you are going for.  YOu can use js, html, and cookies to do basic information retention.

Comment: do not need to save them in database or use php at all use cookie  with javascript and save thoes variables

Comment: Won't I lose the data if the user deletes the cookies on their system?